# mouse over "a" element to display "p" element on page

Tags: javascript

could someone please write me  some javaScript to show how I can mouse over an "a href" element to display a "p" element paragraph on the page.

I have the paragraph displayed:none with css; I want to associate the mouse over of a link to display the paragraph.

cheers

Comment: We are not here to write code for you!! Can you please share what have you tried till now? This is really simple jquery

Comment: read on these:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Comment: thanks yea sorry been a long day was being lazy

Comment: Lazy is not a word allowed in stackoverflow. Ask a question is a task with a minimal effort, but before ask you need to try something. Here is not a normal forum, and this question have zillions of trillions along internet. Should be closed as offtopic. Try to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before ask next time

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use JS for this. You can do this using css also.

```
<a href="#link" class="hoverOn">
    <p class="hoverContent">This is hover content</p>
</a>

<style>
p.hoverContent{
    display:none;
}
a.hoverOn:hover p.hoverContent{
    display:block !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I like the CSS-only approach, but dislike the use of `!important` when it could've / should've been avoided. Kudos for thinking outside the box, though

Comment: @sosro: Mark this answer as correct answer. As, the user has helped you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [jQuery .hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="mousehoverhere"> Link Hover </a>
<p id="para">Hidden text goes here</p>
```

JS

```
$("#mousehoverhere").hover(
    function() {
        /* Effect during hover */
        $("#para").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
        /* Effect after un-hover */
        $("#para").slideUp(500);
    }
);
```

CSS

```
#para {
    display: none;
}
```

Check the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e10tsbty/)

Comment: Why is there a big block of text about Lorem Ipsum in this answer? Also, you might want to add a code example for the html, in addition to the js and css.

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you are not using jQuery, so you can use this piece of code to show the element when you hover the link.

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  document.getElementById("paragraph").style.display = "block";
});
```

You need to replace `link` and `paragraph` with the ID of your link and paragraph.

To also hide the paragraph again when your mouse leaves the link, add this code too:

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  document.getElementById("paragraph").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Assuming there's tons of zillions of articles explaining this kind of stuff, this answer is unneccesary. Stackoverflow is not a forum, this kind of questions are offtopic and should be closed.

Answer (score -2):

I have made an example for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var link = $('#myLink');
  link.on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.lorem').show();
  })
})
```

```css
.lorem {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="localhost" id="myLink">my link</a>

<p class="lorem">
  lorem ipsum
</p>
```